# How to filter blobs in Azure SDK for Python

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-python-sdk

I want to search for blobs in my Azure blob storage according to a specific tag (like: `.name`, `.creation_date`, `.size`...)

My current way is returning all blobs from the container with `MyContainerClient.list_blobs` and searching for the corresponding tag afterwards. Since my container stores around 800000 blobs, this takes me around 20 min, which is not usable for a live view of the content.

But I also found another ContainerClient function: `.find_blobs_by_tags(filter_expression: str)` where I can search for a specific blob whose tags matches the specified condition.

In the Azure API they specified this `filter_expression` as: `""yourtagname"='firsttag'"` , therefore I specified: `""name"='example.jpg'"` or `""creation_date"='2021-07-04 09:35:19+00:00'"`

[Azure SDK Python - ContainerClient.find_blobs_by_tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-containerclient-find-blobs-by-tags)

Unfortunately I always get an error:

```
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: Error parsing query at or near character position 1: unexpected 'creation_time'
RequestId:63bd850b-401e-005f-745e-400d5a000000
Time:2022-03-25T15:40:22.4156367Z
ErrorCode:InvalidQueryParameterValue
queryparametername:where
queryparametervalue:'creation_time'='0529121f-7676-46c7-8a52-424664774240/0529121f-7676-46c7-8a52-424664774240.json'
reason:This query parameter value is invalid.
Content: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidQueryParameterValue</Code><Message>Error parsing query at or near character position 1: unexpected &apos;creation_time&apos;
RequestId:63bd850b-401e-005f-745e-400d5a000000
Time:2022-03-25T15:40:22.4156367Z</Message><QueryParameterName>where</QueryParameterName><QueryParameterValue>&apos;creation_time&apos;=&apos;0529121f-7676-46c7-8a52-424664774240/0529121f-7676-46c7-8a52-424664774240.json&apos;</QueryParameterValue><Reason>This query parameter value is invalid.</Reason></Error>
```

Has someone experience with this Azure function calls?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/_blob_service_client.py) code(in the *find_blobs_by_tags* function) , it says :

```
:param str filter_expression:
             The expression to find blobs whose tags matches the specified condition.
            eg. "\"yourtagname\"='firsttag' and \"yourtagname2\"='secondtag'"
```

Looks like you are missing the escape characters? Can you try including them in?

Comment: Hey, with this expression I'm not getting the InvalidQueryParameterValue error any more, unfortunately it is still not possible for me to get the blob paramters of the return iterator. When passing `returned_iterator.next()` I'm getting: `This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.` Does somebody know how to change permission rights for the Storage Queue Data Contributor?

Comment: You will need atleast Storage Blob Data Reader role/permissions. You are trying to list blobs. Storage Queue Data Contributor is for storage queue only and has no access to the blobs.  If you refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles it says that with Storage Blob Data Reader role you can read and list containers and blobs. Give that a go.